# How can i apply or use selenium testing to php sites

Tags: php, joomla, selenium

I mostly buil sites in php/joomla/jquery. Someone told me to learn some unit testing system like selenium.

I want to know that , can i use that for php sites or only java based sites.
When i was learning j2ee then i find many testing systems but i don't know those work with php and joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can be used for PHP sites.  Easiest path to getting started is (or was at one time, at least) to download the Seleneium IDE plugin for Firefox and use it to build tests.  It can then export your tests as code into a number of different languages.

By the way, I don't consider Selenium a **unit** test tool.  For unit testing in PHP, check out something like PHPunit.

Comment: Actually i am new to testing , so it means that i don't need to change my coding style to use that system . In java we have to write completely diff class for testing